# Sistema de Gerenciamento de fila de Banco

Tags: java

Olá pessoal necessito de uma ajuda estou aprender a programar agora, estou a desenvolver um sistema de senha para fila de espera do tipo banco em JAVA, com base de Dados Mysql.

Senha Normal;
Senha Prioritária;

Chamar em Senha
Reclamar Senha

Visor (Form para Senha)

**Segue ai a minha classe Senha**

```
package Modelo;


public class Senha {

private int senha;
private Boolean chamada;
private DateTime inicioAtendimento;
private  Boolean prioritaria;


    public int getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }


    public void setSenha(int senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }


    public Boolean getChamada() {
        return chamada;
    }

    public void setChamada(Boolean chamada) {
        this.chamada = chamada;
    }


    public DateTime getInicioAtendimento() {
        return inicioAtendimento;
    }


    public void setInicioAtendimento(DateTime inicioAtendimento) {
        this.inicioAtendimento = inicioAtendimento;
    }


    public Boolean getPrioritaria() {
        return prioritaria;
    }


    public void setPrioritaria(Boolean prioritaria) {
        this.prioritaria = prioritaria;
    }
    }
```

**Classe Gerar Senha**

**Meu Botão Chamar Senha**

```
private void btChamarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

            senha  novo = new senha();
            novo.GeraSenha();
            label1.Text = "Atendimento Prioritário";
            label2.Text =" Senha: " +novo.GeraSenha();
        }
```

A minha duvida é se estou a caminha bem e quais são as classes que eu devo utilizar para este fim

Agradecia a ajuda estou a fazer este projeto para  Universidade.

Comment: Qual sua dúvida?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Sistema de Gerenciamento de fila de esopera Banco](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111304/sistema-de-gerenciamento-de-fila-de-esopera-banco)

Comment: Também me parece, @rubStackOverflow. Mas votei pra fechar a outra, porque essa foi a primeira aberta pelo AP.